# Convert Data from yyyy-dd-mm to mm/dd/yyyy Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my table with Dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd I want to convert all the dates in that column to the format mm/dd/yyyy

I am using the below query

```
UPDATE Test.dbo.Status  
   SET DateIn  = CONVERT(DATE,DateIn ,101)
```

The DateIn column is defined as Date in my table (DateIn DATE NULL)

The query does no change to the data. am I doing some thing wrong here?

Comment: A date does not have a format in that sense. A *string representation* of a date does. Use a string representation for presentation and keep dates as dates internally.

Comment: If the field is Date type no matter the format on the column, it is a date. To see it in the format you want you have to configure your database to that. Something like `sp_configure 'default language', 0 reconfigure with override` google it

Comment: I feel as if I have read this question multiple times. Does anyone feel like writing a reference question/answer which explains how things really are ("Your date is *not* in the format yyyy-mm-dd currently...") and which can be used to "close as duplicate" this kind of question?

Comment: I understand I can't change the format once I store the date in the DateTime format using the Convert feature but, if I store it in Varchar and use the query it still of no use. UPDATE Test.dbo.Status  
   SET DateIn  = CONVERT(Varchar,DateIn ,101)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default format in which SQL Server displays a date, but you can't alter the way a `DATE` value is stored via `CONVERT()`.  You can format a date however you want if you store it as a string, but you lose functionality when you do that and it's not advisable.  If you are hell-bent on storing a formatted version, you might want to create a new `VARCHAR()` field so you can preserve your `DATE` version.

You're better off formatting the date at the application level.

The reason your query does nothing is that the actual `DATE` values are equivalent.  Notice when you take any valid date format and `CAST()` it as `DATE` the resulting format is the same regardless of the input:

```
SELECT CAST('20040510' AS DATE)
SELECT CAST('2004-05-10' AS DATE)
SELECT CAST('May 10, 2004' AS DATE)
```

All return: `2004-05-10` on my instance of SQL Server.

Comment: can I make any change if I store the date as Varchar instead of Date?

Comment: @user3614477 If you store the date as a varchar you can store any string in any format you like.  However, like GoatCo said, at that point you can't sort or filter by date.